# Interface problems with Typescript - Angular 7

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I'm create interfaces for some returns in my API
The page works fine, but in console show many errors
"Cannot read property "example" of undefined"
My error dont are the same of javascript, because I return data in typescript and this error show only because the angular interpolation

I tried to make diferent interfaces, with help of some devs
But the error never die

Interface:

```
export interface Banner {
  ds_Imagem: string;
  ds_titulo: string;
}
```

banner.component.html

```
<div id="inicio">


  <div class="carousel" style="min-height: 43vh">

    <a [style.backgroundImage]="'url('+ banner[0]?.ds_Imagem +')'" class="carousel-item" href="{{banner[0].ds_link}}" style="width: 100vw; min-height: 43vh;
      background-repeat: space; background-size: 100% 100%;">
      <div class="textoCentral">
        <span>{{banner[0]?.ds_titulo}}</span>
      </div>
    </a>

    <a [style.backgroundImage]="'url('+ banner[1].ds_Imagem +')'" class="carousel-item" href="{{banner[1].ds_link}}" style="width: 100vw; min-height: 43vh;
      background-repeat: space; background-size: 100% 100%;">
      <div class="textoCentral">
        <span>{{banner[1]?.ds_titulo}}</span>
      </div>
    </a>

    <a [style.backgroundImage]="'url('+ banner[2].ds_Imagem +')'" class="carousel-item" href="{{banner[2].ds_link}}" style="width: 100vw; min-height: 43vh;
      background-repeat: space; background-size: 100% 100%;">
      <div class="textoCentral">
        <span>{{banner[2]?.ds_titulo}}</span>
      </div>
    </a>

  </div>
</div>
```

Error:

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
    at Object.eval [as updateRenderer] (SLIDERComponent.html:6)
    at Object.debugUpdateRenderer [as updateRenderer] (core.js:23937)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:23312)
    at callViewAction (core.js:23548)
    at execComponentViewsAction (core.js:23490)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:23313)
    at callViewAction (core.js:23548)
    at execComponentViewsAction (core.js:23490)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:23313)
    at callWithDebugContext (core.js:24177)
```

Object from API

```
[
{
ds_Imagem: "http://gtw4.ska.com.br/desk_target_magnus/Files/bannertarget-06.png",
ds_titulo: null
},
{
ds_Imagem: "http://gtw4.ska.com.br/desk_target_magnus/Files/Unimed-Banner.png",
ds_titulo: null
},
{
ds_Imagem: "http://gtw4.ska.com.br/desk_target_magnus/Files/setembro-amarelo_2019092603245511.png",
ds_titulo: null
}
]
```

Banner Service

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class BannerService {

  private readonly api = 'http://gtw4.ska.com.br:5007/Banner';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
  }

  list() {
    return this.http.get<Banner[]>(this.api)
      .pipe(
        tap(console.log)
      );
  }
}
```

banner.component.ts

```
export class SLIDERComponent implements OnInit {

  banner: Banner[] = [];
  //banner$: Observable<Banner[]>;
  constructor(private service: BannerService) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    // this.banner = this.service.list();
    this.service.list()
      .subscribe(dados => this.banner = dados);
  }

}
```

Comment: is the `banner` object coming from API??

Comment: can you share your component or service please

Comment: Provide a [mcve] reproducing your issue.

Comment: Done! More infos added

Comment: not sure what the return type of the pipe. I usually use subscribe to do that kind of operation

Comment: You have a example, for use in this case?

Comment: Add the code of your component that is calling the service

Comment: Done! Component

Comment: the problem is not the interface. your banner property has no items and in the template you try to get a property from an undefined item.

Comment: What you can do to avoid it is to put the ? symbol before you get the property. Example: banner[0]?.ds_titulo. This way the property will be checked only if the banner[0] return something that is not null or undefined.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detecting an undefined object property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27509/detecting-an-undefined-object-property)

Comment: This is dont in javascript, the error is in typescript of Angular 7

Answer (score 1):

I would try

```
public banners:Banner[] = undefined;

list():void {
    this.http.get<Banner[]>(this.api).subscribe(
      (data) => this.banners = data,
      (err) => console.log(err)
    )
}
```

then in your html you could do something like

```
<a *ngIf="banners != undefined">
    <span>{{banners[0].ds_titulo}}</span>
</a>
```

you could also use the service which returns the observable and then subscribe into your component

Comment: I tried to use Observable, but the images cant load on the slider

Comment: the error still the same, but using observable the imagens dont show

Comment: Using console.log?
The return is the same, array(3)

Comment: How could I do this?
When I use ".subscribe (data => this.banner = data)"
Don't I do this already?

Comment: `suscribe((data)=>{this.banner = data; console.log(this.banner)})`

Comment: Dont change nothing :/

Comment: Yes! I see data on console

Comment: so this is really weird if you get the data passed to `this.banners` then your view should be updated did you changed the `onChangeDetection` property? Also are you trying to call your variable from a child to a parent component?

Answer (score 1):

If it appears at the runtime, then it's not an interface problem and it's not a TypeScript problem, it's that you're trying to access a property of undefined object. Before accessing `banner[0].someProperty` make sure that `banner` exists and that `banner[0]` exists:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="banner?.length">
    <a [style.backgroundImage]="'url('+ banner[0].ds_Imagem +')'">
...
```

Comment: If it did not exist, it would not appear on the screen. Right?
But the information is passed correctly to the screen. Everything looks fine, but these errors continue on the console.

Comment: These errors are from _before_ `banner` is populated with data. A check will protect you from that (and possibly from Angular messing up the view in an unexpected way - BTDT...)

Comment: What check I can make?

Comment: This `*ngIf` in my answer.

Comment: If i use *ngIf banner[0] no have changes, and the error is the same
And if I use *ngIf banner.lenght, dont show anything on screen and in console I receive "SLIDERComponent.html:4 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined"

Comment: It's `"banner?.length"`. With the `?` safe navigation operator. Again, to avoid accessing a property of _undefined_.

Comment: The error goes away, but does not display anything on the screen.

Comment: Nothing appears because you dont have nothing to show.

Comment: How not? If I using banner[0] works, but banner without [0] is undefined. I dont understand this

Answer (score 0):

Add a template property check using the "?" before access your property:

```css
.link {
 width: 100vw;
 min-height: 43vh;
 background-repeat: space;
 background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

```html
<a [style.backgroundImage]="'url(' + banner[0]?.ds_Imagem +')'"
   class="carousel-item link"
   href="#">
  <div class="textoCentral">
    <span>{{banner[0]?.ds_titulo}}</span>
  </div>
</a>
```

## Edition

you must also to set the banner to an empty array as default value before you set from the api.

```html
banner: Banner[] = [];
```

Comment: This "?" dont change nothing

Comment: The error change to "ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'ds_Imagem' of undefined"